# How to call jquery function then fire click event of button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I need to call jquery function before fire the click event of button but in my case click event fired before calling the jquery function.
My button is:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConfrm" runat="server" Text="View" ForeColor="Black" Width="80px" CssClass="button" Height="30px" ValidationGroup="btn" OnClientClick="ConfirmDialog()" OnClick="OnConfirm" />
```

JQuery function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
     confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";

    function ConfirmDialog() {
        $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
.html('<div><h4>' + 'Do you wanto to see previous data' + '?</h4></div>')
.dialog({
    modal: true, title: 'Carry forward!', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
    width: 'auto', resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        Yes: function () {
            //                $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');
            //                $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();

            $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>Yes</i></h1>');
            $(this).dialog("close");
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        },
        No: function () {
            $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>No</i></h1>');
            $(this).dialog("close");
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);

    }; 
</script>
```

And Event is:

```
Public Sub OnConfirm(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn_show.Click

    Dim confirmValue As String = Request.Form("confirm_value")

    Session("confirm") = confirmValue

    If confirmValue = "Yes" Then
        gvCustomers.Visible = True
        grdblank.Visible = False

        Fill_grid()
    Else

        gvCustomers.Visible = False
        grdblank.Visible = True


        'End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I am getting the confirm_value from the jquery function but in the button click event value is nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the user clicks the button, your javascript-method will be called but right after that the postback to the server will happen and your dialog will not be there anymore. So you need some way to show the dialog before the postback will happen.

There are number of ways, here is one example. It will cancel the original postback by adding "return false" to the OnClientClick (OnClientClick="***ConfirmDialog(); return false;***"), and if the user clicks "Yes" it will execute the postback. That way, your buttons click-event on the server side will only execute if the user clicks "Yes":

Page code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConfrm" runat="server" Text="View" ForeColor="Black" Width="80px" CssClass="button" Height="30px" ValidationGroup="btn" OnClientClick="ConfirmDialog(); return false;" OnClick="OnConfirm" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmDialog() {
        $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
            .html('<div><h4>' + 'Do you wanto to see previous data' + '?</h4></div>')
            .dialog({
                modal: true, title: 'Carry forward!', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    Yes: function () {
                        <%= ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnConfrm, Nothing) %>                            
                    },
                    No: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
    };
</script>
```

And on the server side:

```
Public Sub OnConfirm(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn_show.Click
        gvCustomers.Visible = True
        grdblank.Visible = False

        Fill_grid()       
End Sub
```

Comment: The `confirm_value` is nothing in a server side whereas i select yes or no from the dialog. Ok i will set the visible property in a different way. Thanks.

Comment: If i wanna call the other method on  click `No` from dialog, what should i do for it?

Answer (score 0):

Change OnClientClick="return ConfirmDialog();"

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConfrm" runat="server" Text="View" ForeColor="Black" Width="80px" CssClass="button" Height="30px" ValidationGroup="btn" OnClientClick="return ConfirmDialog();" OnClick="OnConfirm" />
```